# Unity prefab acting weird?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, load, gameobject, unity-editor

I wrote some code that allows the user to instantiate objects in editor mode by loading the input images in streaming assets and then creating objects using these images.

This has worked well, the problem is when I try to create a prefab with one of these objects. For some reason, the image is not saved in the prefab, and so when I load that prefab, I get white images instead of the ones that were in the original gameobject.

Update: It turns out that my background screen is actually working correctly, but none of the other gameobjects are. So I am not sure what is wrong and why it is only working for some objects but not the other.

here is my code:

```c#
public class PlacementObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private loadbackgroundImages backgroundReference;
    public Sprite mouseShape;
    private Image mouseSprite;
    private RectTransform mouseMovement;
    public Canvas myCanvas;
    private int currentState = 0;
    private bool canMove = true;
    public List<Texture2D> allButtons;
    private List<Sprite> allButtonsSprite;
    private List<Sprite> allUISprites;
    private List<Texture2D> allUIElements;
    private int uiButtonStates = 0;
    private int uiElementStates = 0;
    public GameObject afterImport;
    private GameObject clonedObject;
    public GameObject child;

    public GameObject objectToBeExported;
    private bool isLoading = true;
    private bool isfinishedUploading;
    private Vector2 defaultSize;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        allUIElements = new List<Texture2D>();
        allButtons = new List<Texture2D>();
        var info = new DirectoryInfo(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "UIButtons");
        var fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfo)
        {
            if (file.Extension == ".png" || file.Extension == ".jpg")
            {

                StartCoroutine(uploadButtonImages(System.IO.Path.Combine("file:///" + Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UIButtons/" + file.Name)));
            }
        }
        var info2 = new DirectoryInfo(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "UIElements");
        var fileInfo2 = info2.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file2 in fileInfo2)
        {
            if (file2.Extension == ".png" || file2.Extension == ".jpg")
            {

                StartCoroutine(uploadUiImages(System.IO.Path.Combine("file:///" + Application.streamingAssetsPath, "UIElements/" + file2.Name)));
            }
        }

        allButtonsSprite = new List<Sprite>();
        allUISprites = new List<Sprite>();
        //createSpritesForButtons(allButtons);
        // createSpritesForElements(allUIElements);
        mouseSprite = GetComponent<Image>();
        mouseSprite.sprite = mouseShape;
        mouseMovement = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        backgroundReference = FindObjectOfType<loadbackgroundImages>();
        isfinishedUploading = true;
        defaultSize = mouseMovement.sizeDelta;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print(isLoading);
        if (isfinishedUploading && backgroundReference.isfinished)
        {
            isLoading = false;
        }

        Cursor.visible = false;
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector2 pos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(myCanvas.transform as RectTransform, Input.mousePosition, myCanvas.worldCamera, out pos);
        transform.position = myCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(pos);


        if (isLoading == false)
        {
            if (currentState == 2)
            {
                mouseSprite.sprite = allUISprites[uiElementStates];
            }
            if (currentState == 1)
            {
                mouseSprite.sprite = allButtonsSprite[uiButtonStates];


            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
            {
                currentState = 0;
                mouseSprite.sprite = mouseShape;
                mouseMovement.sizeDelta = defaultSize;
            }



            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            {
                currentState = 1;

            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
            {
                currentState = 2;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                placeObject();
            }

            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 && canMove)
            {
                canMove = false;

                if (currentState == 0)
                {
                    changeBackgroundNext();
                }
                else if (currentState == 1)
                {
                    changeButtonNext();
                }
                else if (currentState == 2)
                {
                    changeElementNext();
                }

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                rotateObject();
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
            {

                if (currentState == 1 || currentState == 2)
                {
                    mouseMovement.sizeDelta -= new Vector2(1, 1);
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
            {
                if (currentState == 1 || currentState == 2)
                {
                    mouseMovement.sizeDelta += new Vector2(1, 1);
                }
            }


            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 && canMove)
            {

                canMove = false;
                if (currentState == 0)
                {
                    changeBackgroundPrev();
                }
                else if (currentState == 1)
                {
                    changeButtonPrev();
                }
                else if (currentState == 2)
                {
                    changeElementPrev();
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
            {
                canMove = true;

            }


            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                var newBackgroundSprite = backgroundReference.allSprites[backgroundReference.imageIndex];
                backgroundReference.imageReference.sprite = newBackgroundSprite;


                // exportObject();
                // importObject();
#if UNITY_EDITOR
              var prefab =  PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab( "Assets/Resources/Image.prefab", FindObjectOfType<loadbackgroundImages>().gameObject);

                AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif

            }
        }
    }
    void rotateObject()
    {
        if (currentState == 1 || currentState == 2)
            mouseMovement.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    }
    private void exportObject()
    {
        UIData saveData = new UIData();
        saveData.inputObject = objectToBeExported;


        //Save data from PlayerInfo to a file named players
        DataSaver.saveData(saveData, "UI");


    }
    public void importObject()
    {
        UIData loadedData = DataSaver.loadData<UIData>("UI");
        if (loadedData == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Display loaded Data
        Debug.Log("Life: " + loadedData.inputObject);
        afterImport = loadedData.inputObject;


    }
    private void changeBackgroundNext()
    {
        backgroundReference.imageIndex++;
        if (backgroundReference.imageIndex >= backgroundReference.allSprites.Count)
        {
            backgroundReference.imageIndex = 0;
        }

    }
    private void changeButtonNext()
    {
        uiButtonStates++;
        if (uiButtonStates >= allButtonsSprite.Count)
        {
            uiButtonStates = 0;
        }

    }
    private void changeElementNext()
    {
        uiElementStates++;
        if (uiElementStates >= allUISprites.Count)
        {
            uiElementStates = 0;
        }

    }
    private void changeElementPrev()
    {
        uiElementStates--;
        if (uiElementStates < 0)
        {
            uiElementStates = allUISprites.Count - 1;
        }

    }
    private void changeButtonPrev()
    {
        uiButtonStates--;
        if (uiButtonStates < 0)
        {
            uiButtonStates = allButtonsSprite.Count - 1;
        }

    }
    private void changeBackgroundPrev()
    {
        backgroundReference.imageIndex--;
        if (backgroundReference.imageIndex < 0)
        {
            backgroundReference.imageIndex = backgroundReference.allSprites.Count - 1;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator uploadButtonImages(string url)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        yield return www;
        if (www != null)
        {
            allButtons.Add(www.texture);
            allButtonsSprite.Add(Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)));
        }
    }

    private void createSpritesForButtons(List<Texture2D> allTextures)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < allTextures.Count; i++)
        {
            Sprite tempSprite = Sprite.Create(allTextures[i], new Rect(0, 0, allTextures[i].width, allTextures[i].height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            tempSprite.name = "Button" + i;
            allButtonsSprite.Add(tempSprite);

        }


    }
    IEnumerator uploadUiImages(string url)
    {

        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        yield return www;
        print(url);
        if (www != null)
        {
            allUIElements.Add(www.texture);
            allUISprites.Add(Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)));
        }
    }
    private void createSpritesForElements(List<Texture2D> allTextures)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < allTextures.Count; i++)
        {
            Sprite tempSprite = Sprite.Create(allTextures[i], new Rect(0, 0, allTextures[i].width, allTextures[i].height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            tempSprite.name = "" + i;

            allUISprites.Add(tempSprite);

        }


    }

    private void placeObject()
    {
        if (currentState == 1)
        {
            var gameObject = Instantiate(child, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(mouseMovement.eulerAngles.x, mouseMovement.eulerAngles.y, mouseMovement.eulerAngles.z), backgroundReference.transform);
            gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(mouseMovement.sizeDelta.x, mouseMovement.sizeDelta.y);
            var newSprite = allButtonsSprite[uiButtonStates];
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;
            gameObject.AddComponent<Button>();
        }

        if (currentState == 2)
        {
            var gameObject = Instantiate(child, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(mouseMovement.eulerAngles.x, mouseMovement.eulerAngles.y, mouseMovement.eulerAngles.z), backgroundReference.transform);
            gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(mouseMovement.sizeDelta.x, mouseMovement.sizeDelta.y);
            var newSprite = allUISprites[uiElementStates];
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're changing some object's state via an inspector script you have to tell Unity, that you've done some changes, otherwise it doesn't know that something has happened to objects at the scene. And according to the information about changes on your scene (also when you change it manually, not by script) Unity serializes all data on your scene to save all the information. And when you load scene (doesn't matter in editor or in play mode) Unity deserializes all the objects on scene to show you. As far as serializing/deserializng object is rather expensive operation Unity only does it when it's really necessary - in case of saving scene/object it's only performed when it knows that there're some changes that needs to be saved.

The actual solution of your problem depends on Unity version you're using. Try reading this [post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1232239/unity-editor-not-saving-object-changes.html). Such things as [Undo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.html) and [MarkAllScenesDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkAllScenesDirty.html) should help you. For older versions of Unity [EditorUtility.SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) should help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so I tried undo.record(gameobject, "added changes) and I put that inside the place object function for both cases, but it still doesn't work. Should I place it in something else? the script documents are kind of vague.

Comment: @SamBasiony After adding undo, and making changes to objects, does your Unity show that there are changes on scene? (It will mark the name of the scene in the hierarchy  window with asterisk (*) after the name). Try also mark the scene dirty after every change you make to the object on scene

Comment: i tried marking scene dirty, and it didn't work because it said it can't work in runtime. But no problem because I just found a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

So as people pointed out like Vmchar, when you save the prefab using code. it gets saved using the initial state without any of the stuff that got loaded to it during runtime.

I found out a solution for this though, all you need to do is make a script that would save the image by serializing it in streamingassets (plenty of tutorials online on how to serialize image), and then loading it using www stream when needed in the other scene.